# How to debug Dagger2 not generating components

Tags: java, dagger-2, dagger

Is there a way to get dagger to spit out *why* it didn't generate a particular component?

I tried refactoring some of our modules and ended up breaking something, but *I have literally no idea what I broke!* All I see is that all my `DaggerFoo` components are missing, because dagger is apparently silently failing.

I've tried compiling with verbosity & higher max errors, but I still see absolutely *nothing* from Dagger itself saying what went wrong.

```
-Xdiags:verbose
-Xmaxerrs=1000
```

I have no relevant errors to share, because none are printed!

How the heck do you debug Dagger2?

Comment: Java app. I tried the log level from your link, but still no dice. Complete radio silence from Dagger. I've spent a few hours on this, so I'm just going to give up, roll back, and re-introduce my changes one by one T_T

Comment: @paulsm4 Unfortunately there's a name collision here: https://dagger.io/ is a "a portable devkit for CI/CD pipelines"; OP you were looking for "fully static, compile-time dependency injection framework for Java" documented at https://dagger.dev/.

Comment: @Jeff Bowman - whoops.  Thank you!  And +1 on your excellent reply below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dagger runs as an annotation processor, so its error messages will manifest as compiler errors. These will often look like [this message](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49943809/1426891) ("X cannot be provided...").

```
error: some.injected.ClassName cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor
    or from an @Provides- or @Produces-annotated method.
some.injected.ClassName is injected at
some.class.that.InjectsIt
some.class.that.InjectsThatAbove
some.class.that.FurtherInjectsThat
```

If you're not sure where to look for compiler errors, you can see some other answers here:

- [Android Studio: Where is the Compiler Error Output Window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16633956/android-studio-where-is-the-compiler-error-output-window)
- [How to view the list of compile errors in IntelliJ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19364949/how-to-view-the-list-of-compile-errors-in-intellij)
- [eclipse annotation processor not working. Where are errors shown?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44153959/1426891)

If you've edited your project configuration or Gradle definition, it is also possible that Dagger is no longer running at all, or that it hasn't run for a while and has been working only based on its previous output. If so, check your Gradle file or Eclipse project definition to ensure that you are including Dagger as an `annotationProcessor`, and that you have at least one `@Component` file for that annotation processor to find.